# How to sum values in a column of a bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sum

I want to sum values of a particular column of a dynamic bootstrap table. There are many such tables, the number of tables is also dynamic.

Finally I want to sum those values of all tables (same column, different tables, I want to sum all the values).

Comment: Share your html and script

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap table in fact is a simple decorated html table, you can use next approach using jquery

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr class="titlerow">
        <td>Column1</td>
        <td>Column2</td>
        <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">11</td>
        <td class="col2">22</td>
        <td class="col3">33</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $dataRows=$("#table1 tr:not('.titlerow')");
    var col1Total = 0;

    $dataRows.each(function() {
        var col1 = $(this).find('.col1'); 
        col1Total += parseInt(col1.html());
    });
});
```

col1Total is a number you are looking for.

And in case of several tables just use selector like

```
var $dataRows=$("#table1 tr:not('.titlerow'), #table2 tr:not('.titlerow')");
```

the selector, probably, can be optimized